# Make rednet.receive() passive on Computercraft

Tags: networking, lua, computercraft

Computer 0 is a central computer that is meant to receive info from terminals elsewhere, interpret the info, and send it to a monitor. I will have the outside terminals sending info at different rates. Some several times per second, others maybe one update per minute. 
The basic idea is simple.
Computer 0

```
local mon = peripheral.wrap("top")
rednet.open("right")

local id = nil
local msg = {}
while true do
    mon.clear()
    id, smsg = rednet.receive()
    if smsg ~= nil then
        msg[id]= smsg
    end
    for i = 1,#msg do
        mon.setCursorPos(1,i)
        mon.write(msg[i])
    sleep(0.1)
end
```

Other computers

```
rednet.open("top")
local n=1
while true do
    rednet.broadcast(0,n)
    n = n+1
    sleep(0.5) --Sleep timer is arbitrary. I just want the central computer to update each individual computers info as they come in.
end
```

Yes I understand this will cause havoc, but I just want to get the basic idea working. Then I can ID and protocol check as needed later.
I know enough to know that I need to do some parallel stuff but that's about it. I'm still kinda new to this thing, at bast I'd be just above beginner.

Comment: I don't see what our question is supposed to be. Also `if smsg ~= nil then` can just be written as `if smsh then` since everything other than `false` or `nil` evaluates to true. Anyway, what's your question?

Comment: I believe [this](http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/27457-passive-rednetreceive/) is the same person.  I've answered your question there.

Comment: @KingofGamesYami Yes I am, and Yes you did. Kind of. I posted here because of the mod approval thing taking all day on the site. I figured it out with a while loop and parallel commands.

Comment: @MiuKujo glad it worked out!